# How to append a string in between a string for multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

trying to update a table which is something like this , the desired output is the second table .... Looking for an update query in SQL that can add a string in between a given string............................................

```html
<table>
 <tr>
 <!--<td >ID</td>-->
 <td>ID</td>
 <td>ProductName</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <!--<td rowspan="3">1</td>-->
 <td>1</td>
 <td>H2413_H1_2013_Lotus</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td>2</td>
<td>H2413_P1_2013_Lotus</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>3</td>
<td>H2413_T1_2013_Lotus</td>

</tr>
<!--<tr><td colspan="3">---------------------</td></tr>-->
<tr>
<!--<td>ID</td>-->
<td>ID</td>
<td>ProductName</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<!--<td rowspan="3">2</td>-->
<td>1</td>
<td>H2413_H1_2013_Det_Lotus</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>2</td>
<td>H2413_P1_2013_Det_Lotus</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>3</td>
<td>H2413_T1_2013_Det_Lotus</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should explain your update logic. I mean we can try to guess is insert  `_Det` after every `2013` or after the 14 char

Comment: @achilies, I'm really confused now. The first table you are showing is a HTML table. However you have tagged this question as a SQL update issue. Does your data exist in a sql table?

Comment: Basically, all I need is to insert _Det_ in between "2013" and "Lotus" to get the desired output

Comment: @John: I used the HTML code to draw the table and show what I am dealing with here, to show the actual table and my desired output. All I really want is an update query to get the desired output

Comment: @achilies, ok then the code in my answer below will do the update as required on SQL server

Comment: @john: what if we may not insert "_Det_" after every 14th character, if the length of the string is not fixed. The pattern that I am looking for is appending "_Det_" after "2013" and before "Lotus"

Comment: @achilies - there must be some pattern you can match on, e.g. after a particular set omatch on?f characters etc. Can you specify what pattern you can

Comment: @John: The pattern that I am looking for is to insert the "_Det_" between "2013" and "Lotus"

Comment: ok - answer below has been updated to meet these requirements

Comment: @John: thanks John, that was very helpful :-)

Comment: @achilies - could you please accept the answer below if this has resolved your question. Please see here on how to accept an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here that the 2013 value can change in the product name. Take a look at the Replace Command

Using Replace something like this should work

```
UPDATE 
    Products 
SET 
    ProductName = REPLACE(ProductName,'2013_Lotus', '2013_DET_Lotus')
```

Comment: Q: in this case will replace the `_` in the 14 position for `_DET_` ?

Comment: @Juan, correct, stuff replaces text so we are telling the update to replace the 14th character with _DET_ to meet OP requirements

Comment: I have added a better looking table by adding some HTML code